# Are the determinants of a lattice discrete?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lattices, arithmetic-groups

Let $\Lambda\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ be a lattice. We identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the space $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb R$. It then is is clear that the set
$$
\det(\Lambda)=\big\{\det(\lambda):\lambda\in\Lambda\big\}
$$
is not necessarily discrete in $\mathbb R$.
But now we additionally insist that the group
$$
\Gamma=\big\{\gamma\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}): \gamma\Lambda=\Lambda\big\}
$$
be a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Under this condition, is the set $\det(\Lambda)$ discrete in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Ignoring the question of discreteness, are there any concrete examples?  (That is, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice, where $\Gamma$ is cocompact and preserves $\Lambda$.)

Comment: @Sam Nead: Yes, let $D$ be a quaternion division algebra over $\mathbb Q$, which is split over $\mathbb R$. Let $O$ be any order in $D$ and let $O^1$ be the elements of reduced norm 1 in $O$. Then $\Lambda=O$ and $\Gamma=O^1$ is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be related to issues of Diophantine approximation.  Fix such $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$.  Fix $\lambda \in \Lambda$ so that $\det(\lambda) \neq 0$.  After rescaling $\Lambda$, we may assume that $\det(\lambda) = 1$.  Fix some $\gamma \in \Gamma$ other than the identity.  Conjugating $\Gamma$ (and transforming $\Lambda$ via the conjugating matrix) we may assume that $\gamma$ is of the following form.
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\
0      & 1/\alpha
\end{pmatrix}

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are integers.
Then $p\lambda$ and $q\lambda$ lie in $\Lambda$, thus so does $p\gamma\lambda$ and thus so does $p\gamma\lambda - q\lambda = (p\gamma - q I) \lambda$.  Here $I$ is the two-by-two identity matrix.

We now compute:
$$
\det(p\gamma\lambda - q\lambda) = \det(p\gamma - qI) \det(\lambda)
                        = p^2 + q^2 - pq(\alpha + 1/\alpha)
$$
So if $\alpha$ has unusually good Diophantine approximations then this quadratic form should "approximate zero".  In this case, $\det(\Lambda)$ is indiscrete.

Comment: Thanks! But the condition of $\Gamma$ being cocompact might forbid such $\alpha$.

Comment: Co-compactness, by itself, imposes no conditions on $\alpha$.  This is because the set of co-compact lattices naturally forms a space, called moduli space, where traces of loxodromic elements vary continuously (and are not constant).

Comment: However, it is possible that your "joint" condition (on $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$ together) could force $\alpha$ to be very special.  Seems interesting!

Comment: Yes indeed, it makes the group arithmetic and arithmetic groups are discrete in the moduli space.